# calculate difference between two times in two rows in sql

Tags: sql-server

I am using MSSQL 2008 Standard

I have multiple rows in a select command which are filled with events. For every event I have got a timestamp, now I want to calculate the time between the events:

```
(number) | event          | timestamp           | duration
---------+----------------+---------------------+----------
 1       | logon          | 2012-05-23 10:00:00 |
 2       | incomming call | 2012-05-23 10:01:00 |
 3       | call ended     | 2012-05-23 10:02:00 |
 4       | logoff         | 2012-05-23 10:04:00 |
```

(the number column does not exist but it's easier for explanation)

Now the duration cell for the first row should be 1, for the second one also 1 and for the third one 2.

Does anybody know how to achieve this without loops and so on.

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure you mean `MSSQL 2010`? There's no such version I'm aware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the CTE answer provided less than desirable due to its not reporting the first line. I found the other answers with join's too complex. I distilled the problem into this snippet

Here is the code which uses a CTE, creates a sequence within the CTE's select which identifies a row number by an ordered timestamp. The resulting selection picks on the resulting ordered rows and determines minutes.

```
WITH AgentActions AS
(
    select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [TimeStamp]) -- Create an index number ordered by time.
         AS [Sequence],
    * from AgentInteractions
)
SELECT *,
       ISNULL(DATEDIFF(Minute, 
                      (SELECT other.TimeStamp 
                              FROM AgentActions Other 
                              WHERE other.Sequence = AgentActions.Sequence - 1 ), 
                       AgentActions.TimeStamp), 
               0) 
    AS MinutesFromLastPoint
FROM AgentActions;
```

Here is the setup table

```
CREATE TABLE AgentInteractions
(
[Event]      VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL, 
[Timestamp] [DateTime] NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO dbo.AgentInteractions( Event, TimeStamp  )
VALUES ( 'Alpha', '1-Jan-2018 3:04:22 PM' ),
       ( 'Omega', '3-Jan-2018 10:04:22 PM' ),
       ( 'Beta', '2-Jan-2018 2:04:22 AM' );
```

Results

[image]

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d02a2/1)</kbd>

Comment: Thank's for that answer, it indeed "looks" good. What I wonder is why you are calculating the difference of the timestamps with a subquery and not a join like in my own solution. I compared it and the estimated execution plan says that the version with the join is 41% and the subquery 59% of the batch.

Comment: I will set your answer as solution, however the join in the end would need to be changed... (as information for anybody else who might need that)

Comment: @Philipp Which version of SQL Server are (or were) you targeting ? There is another way to get previous rows via the `Lag` function starting in SQL Server 2012

Comment: I opened the thread for 2008 standard, but I did the timing analysis on 2012 developer

Answer (score 3):

You need a self join.  Since you need to generate an id then something like:

```
 select t1.*, datediff(minute, t2.timestamp, t1.timestamp) from
     (select *, row_number() over (order by ...) as rowid from MyTable) t1
 inner join 
     (select *, row_number() over (order by ...) as rowid from MyTable) t2
 on t1.rowid = t2.rowid - 1
```

Comment: i need to change the question a little bit: there is currently no id column, this was just a number column to make it easier, do you know a way to maybe create it it the select? The events are out of two tables with a union

Comment: You could put the result into a temp table which has an auto generated id column and then self join that.  You could also look at using row_number() over (...).

Answer (score 1):

This is my current version/solution:

```
declare @temp table
(
    id int,
    timestamp datetime,
    type nvarchar(255),
    skillname nvarchar(255),
    event nvarchar(255),
    userstatus nvarchar(255)
)

insert into @temp (id, timestamp, type, skillname, event, userstatus)
(
    select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by timestamp) as id, * from
    (
        select TimeStamp, 'Event' as type, SkillName, Event, UserStatus from AgentEvents
            where TimeStamp >= '2012-05-22T00:00:00'
                and UserName like '%engel%'
        union
        select TimeStamp, 'Anruf' as type, SkillName, '' as event, '' as status from calls
            where TimeStamp >= '2012-05-22T00:00:00'
                and UserName like '%engel%'
    ) as a 
)

select t1.*, DATEDIFF(second, t1.timestamp, t2.timestamp) as duration 
from @temp t1
left outer join @temp t2 on t1.id = t2.id - 1
```

Edit: changed `inner join` to `left outer join`, otherwise the last row would be lost.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you need to update the duration column.

You can use something like this :

```
update mytable a set duration =  DateDiff( a.timestamp, select top b.timestamp from mytable b order by b.timestamp asc)
```

I cannot test it, but just to give you an idea (it may have some syntax errors).
Using the 'top' with the  'order by' clause should do the trick.

(Edited)

Comment: select top will only work for SQLServer not any other databases

Answer (score 0):

I think you better create a trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_duration ON sometable 
INSTEAD OF INSERT 
AS 
DECLARE @lastDT datetime 
BEGIN
SET @lastDT =
  (SELECT TOP 1 _timestamp
   FROM sometable
   ORDER BY _timestamp DESC)
UPDATE sometable
SET duration = DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @lastDT, GETDATE()) 
END
```

Comment: I am putting 2 tables together by `union`, a trigger is no option.

Answer (score 0):

`WITH rows AS
        (
        SELECT  *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Col1) AS rn
        FROM    dbo.Table_2
        )
SELECT mc.col1, DATEDIFF(HOUR, mc.Col1, mp.Col1) as TimeDiffInHours
FROM    rows mc
JOIN    rows mp
ON   mc.rn = mp.rn-1`

Comment: This causes the resulting data to not report the first row due to `mc.rn = mp.rn-1` which can't match row 1.