# SQL Query to get total duration for each status

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I was researching a similar issue with this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69821154/sql-query-to-get-time-spent-on-specific-statuses-based-on-single-datetime-column) with a slight difference.

This is the script to recreate in SQL Server 2012 Management Studio:

```
CREATE TABLE #Tickets 
(
    TId1 varchar(6), 
    TId2 varchar(6),
    TSubmitBy varchar(200), 
    TDate DATE
);

CREATE TABLE #TiktProcess
(
    TId1 VARCHAR(6), 
    TId2 VARCHAR(6),   
    TProcessDesc VARCHAR(100), 
    TProcessStatus varchar(50),   
    TProcessFullName varchar(200),
    TProcessRecDate Date
);

INSERT INTO #Tickets (TId1, TId2, TSubmitBy, TDate) 
VALUES ('Tikt22', '111111', 'ASmith', '2022-05-01'), 
       ('Tikt22', '111112', 'BSmith', '2022-05-01');

INSERT INTO #TiktProcess (TId1, TId2, TProcessDesc, TProcessStatus, TProcessFullName, TProcessRecDate) 
VALUES  ('Tikt22', '111111', 'Ticket Submitted', 'Submitted', 'ASmith', '2022-05-01'), 
        ('Tikt22', '111111', 'Ticket Submitted', 'Accepted', 'AJohnson', '2022-05-02'), 
        ('Tikt22', '111111', 'Review New', 'Work In Progress', 'AWilliams', '2022-05-02'),  
        ('Tikt22', '111111', 'Review New', 'Assigned', 'AWilliams', '2022-05-05'), 
        ('Tikt22', '111111', 'Assigned Team1', 'Assigned', 'ABrown', '2022-05-05'),
        ('Tikt22', '111111', 'Assigned Team1', 'On Hold', 'BJones', '2022-05-13'), 
        ('Tikt22', '111111', 'Assigned Team2', 'Assigned', 'AGarcia', '2022-05-05'), 
        ('Tikt22', '111111', 'Assigned Team2', 'Work In Progress', 'CSmith', '2022-05-06'),  
        ('Tikt22', '111111', 'Assigned Team2', 'Waiting on Customer', 'BMiller', '2022-05-17'), 
        ('Tikt22', '111111', 'Assigned Team2', 'Accepted', 'ADavis', '2022-02-26'),
        ('Tikt22', '111111', 'Assigned Team1', 'Customer Approve', 'CBrown', '2022-05-13');

SELECT 
    A.TId1,
    B.TProcessDesc, B.TProcessStatus, B.TProcessRecDate, B.TProcessFullName,
    [duration] = DATEDIFF (day, B.TProcessRecDate, 
                           LEAD (B.TProcessRecDate, 1, B.TProcessRecDate) OVER (PARTITION BY B.TProcessDesc 
                                                                              ORDER BY B.TProcessRecDate)),     
    [total_duration] = -DATEDIFF (day, B.TProcessRecDate, 
                                  FIRST_VALUE(B.TProcessRecDate) OVER (PARTITION BY B.TProcessDesc ORDER BY B.TProcessRecDate))     
FROM
    #Tickets A 
JOIN
    #TiktProcess B ON A.TId1 = B.TId1   
                   AND A.TId2 = B.TId2  
WHERE
    B.TId2 = '111111'

/* Desired Results - Question 1
TId1   TId2   TProcessDesc      Total_Duration
Tikt22 111111 Ticket Submitted  1
Tikt22 111111 Review New        3
Tikt22 111111 Assigned Team 1   8
Tikt22 111111 Assigned Team 1   80

Desired Results - Question 2
TId1   TId2   TProcessDesc      Total_Duration TProcessStatus
Tikt22 111111 Ticket Submitted  1              Submitted, Accepted
Tikt22 111111 Review New        3              Assigned, Work In Progress
Tikt22 111111 Assigned Team 1   8              Assigned, On Hold, Customer Approve
Tikt22 111111 Assigned Team 1   80
*/

DROP TABLE #Tickets; 
DROP TABLE #TiktProcess;
```

When I run my select, I get the following:

[image: 2]

1. My question is how do I get `total_duration` for each `TProcessDesc` from the 1st entry to the last entry? For example,
2. Is it possible to concatenate `TProcessStatus` with the results from question 1?

Thank you

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Please show the result you want (not in a picture), instead of describing them. Perhaps using a [db<>fiddle](https://sqlblog.org/fiddle). The requirements as stated are ambiguous to me.

Comment: As per request, https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=94bd365b9be0c5c33601fb9f4e61bf9d

Comment: Do you expect 4 rows in the result? And none of the columns like `TId1`, `TProcessFullName`, and `duration`? Are you really using SQL Server 2014? (Please put desired results in tabular form in the question and/or in the fiddle. They are absolutely unreadable in a comment.)

Comment: I'm trying to get a total sum of days for each process.

Comment: That's still just _describing_ the result, and also you haven't clarified what you mean by `concatenate`.

Comment: I don't know how to format the results. I am on SQL Server 2012. But DB Fiddle only has 2014 and newer.

Comment: Yes, just 4 rows as results using the example - Ticket Submitted, Review New, Assigned Team 1, Assigned Team 2. Concatenate the TProcessStatus for each of the TProcess Desc - For example, Review New, under column TProcessStatus will have Assigned, Work In Progress.

Comment: There's a reason DBFiddle doesn't still support SQL Server 2012 - Microsoft doesn't support it anymore either. (e.g. time to upgrade.)

Comment: I figured it's because of Microsoft ending support on the version. I believe the DB team is working on it. I'm just a very low and very new in this company and industry, so, I'll likely have no say in what they need to be doing.

Comment: You can always provide feedback even if you aren't part of decision-making.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really ugly in SQL Server 2012:

```
SELECT TP.TId1, TP.TId2, TP.TProcessDesc, 
  TProcessStatuses = STUFF((SELECT CONCAT(',', TP2.TProcessStatus)
    FROM #TiktProcess AS TP2
    WHERE TP2.TId1 = TP.TId1 
      AND TP2.TId2 = TP.TId2 
      AND TP2.TProcessDesc = TP.TProcessDesc
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value(N'./text()[1]', N'varchar(max)'),1,1,''),
  Total_Duration = DATEDIFF(DAY, MIN(TP.TProcessRecDate), MAX(TP.TProcessRecDate))
FROM #Tickets AS T 
INNER JOIN #TiktProcess AS TP
ON T.TId1 = TP.TId1 and T.TId2 = TP.TId2 where TP.TId2 = '111111'
GROUP BY TP.TId1, TP.TId2, TP.TProcessDesc;
```

In SQL Server 2017+, you can use the much tidier:

```
SELECT T.TId1, T.TId2, TP.TProcessDesc, 
  TProcessStatuses = STRING_AGG(TP.TProcessStatus, ','), 
  Total_Duration   = DATEDIFF(DAY, MIN(TP.TProcessRecDate), MAX(TP.TProcessRecDate))
FROM #Tickets AS T 
INNER JOIN #TiktProcess AS TP
ON T.TId1 = TP.TId1 and T.TId2 = TP.TId2 where TP.TId2 = '111111'
GROUP BY T.TId1, T.TId2, TP.TProcessDesc;
```

Both produce the same results:

> | TId1 | TId2 | TProcessDesc | TProcessStatuses | Total_Duration |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | Tikt22 | 111111 | Assigned Team1 | Assigned,On Hold,Customer Approve | 8 |
> | Tikt22 | 111111 | Assigned Team2 | Assigned,Work In Progress,Waiting on Customer,Accepted | 80 |
> | Tikt22 | 111111 | Review New | Work In Progress,Assigned | 3 |
> | Tikt22 | 111111 | Ticket Submitted | Submitted,Accepted | 1 |

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017l&fiddle=5654dbe3d5376d1434e47d8358796ebb)

More on string aggregation specifically:

- [String aggregation over the years in SQL Server](https://sqlperformance.com/2022/02/t-sql-queries/string-aggregation-over-the-years-in-sql-server)

As an aside, please don't use [meaningless aliases](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3) like `A` and `B`, and please do read all the links here about [asking a good database question](https://sqlblog.org/ask).

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll check out the link. Is there a link on StackOverflow on how to format - for example, desired results? I put it in comments within code tag - probably not the right way?

Comment: @Trini try a quick google on `displaying tabular data on stackoverflow`

Comment: @Trini You can use simple markdown, see [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/403501/61305) for an example (and [this meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/356997/165455) for background). Also db<>fiddle produces markdown results to copy and paste; just click the link at the top that says `markdown` after you have run the fiddle.

Comment: (This is another reason starting with a fiddle is best.)